# Generate Detailed Commit reports from Git

Tags: windows, git

I have been working on a specific feature in a project and I have done a lot of changes on several pages in my source code in one session and I want to get all those changes.
In the commit window I have all my changed files and when I click on any file on the other side I can see the changes.
[image: Git Commit Window]

I want to view all the changes in this session the same way it is being displayed in the commit window for reviewing later and some other reasons.

For example, generate a pdf file or even a text file with the file name and the changes associated with it.

I don't want to use the history visualization tool because it contains a lot of data that makes it not easy to use it and the way the history displayed is not as simple as the commit window.

I am working under Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Try,
If files are not added to the repo

git diff > /path/to/write/file/diff.txt

If files are added (Staged)

git diff --staged > /path/to/write/file/stageddiff.txt

If files are committed to the repo

git log // get the commit id

git show commitid > /path/to/write/file/diff.txt

Comment: Didn't work, diff > file.txt just produced an empty file!

Comment: @MuhammadNour what is the output for git diff
(without writting it to the file) Which tool are you using on windows ? Is it Cygwin?

Comment: I tried the first one (git diff > file.txt) and I got an empty file!, I haven't yet committed my progress, just staged the changes.

Comment: @MuhammadNour check if 
1) You running this command from root project folder ? i.e where your hidden .git folder of the project is located.
2) Can you check what is the output of git diff (without writting it to the file ) if you are getting expected output then try to write it to the file by giving proper write permissions to the folder.
I am currently on Ubuntu it works like a charm! If your doing 1) and 2) right. Try with Cygwin on windows.

Comment: I am at the root of my project and I am writing with permission and the output of the diff command is nothing it doesn't do anything!

Comment: @MuhammadNour
git diff --staged

this should work. Let me know I will edit my answer as well for staged files